# AttributeError: 'Object has no attribute'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have following block of code:

```
class HwSwitch(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def _create_channel(self):
        try:
            self.channel = self.ssh.invoke_shell()
        except SSHException:
            raise SSHException("Unable to invoke the SSH Command shell")

    def _send_cmd_to_channel(self, cmd):
        try:
            time.sleep(1)
            self.channel.send(cmd + '\r\n')
            out = self.channel.recv(9999)
        except SSHException:
            raise SSHException("Execution of command '%s' failed" % cmd)
        return str(out)
```

But I get always error which says: AttributeError: 'HwSwitch' object has no attribute 'channel'. 
It seems that problem is somewhere at `self.channel.send(cmd + '\r\n')` but I cannot see where. Is there something wrong (maybe indentation?). Thanks

Comment: Can you add an example of when you run the code? I imagine you haven't called `_create_channel`

Comment: N.B. If it were indentation, an IndentationError or SyntaxError would have been raised instead, not an AttributeError.

Comment: you set the `self.channel` only in `_create_channel` method, not in the `__init__` constructor. This means if you touch it without calling the  `_create_channel` method, you'll face that error, i guess this what happens.. Either add is to `__init__` or call `_create_channel` from `__init__`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing 'channel' as an instance variable, either create it in the `__init__` or call `_create_channel` before calling `_send_cmd_to_channel`.

Also refer [this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables)